# ActionScript | Flex | Flash bracketed directives like [SWF...] and [Frame...], what are they? documentation?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, flash, frame

I've seen that this kind of directives like [SWF...] and [Frame...] are used to set things that would otherwise require using the Flash IDE, but this way you set them from within Actionscript code.
I've tried to search for them but as I don't know their name I can't find them, and of course SWF and Frame aren't good search terms.
Where are they documented?
thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Metadata tags.

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=metadata_3.html

Comment: But your link doesn't say anything of [SWF] and [Frame], are you sure it's the same?

Comment: Yeah, just Google `as3 frame metadata` or `as3 swf metadata`.  Here is an example http://www.bit-101.com/blog/?p=946

Comment: Hey thanks! I actually found that article about AS3 preloaders really useful.